# Cursor is not following my selection

Tags: 3d-cursor

[image]I must have changed a something, but my cursor stays in the same place if I select a new vertecies, edge or face. I know I can shift s, but that's just a quick fix. Any ideas what I've to do?[image]

Comment: Please show an image of Blender's whole window so that we can see the settings (Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender). Also share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there.

Comment: it may have something to do with your setting for *Transform Pivot Point*

Comment: I've added the screenshot above. I wanted to share my file, but it's 48 mb even without the model and textures. Any way to downsize it?

Comment: Hello james, where can I find Transform Pivot Point? Thanks

Comment: Transform Pivot point (which is currently set to 3D Cursor) is next to the Transform Orientation which you can see is set to 'Global' in the top status bar. I can't really see either of them causing that issue though, but I'm also confused by the fact that you should be in X-ray mode according to the top-right icon, but the view is clearly in solid view!

Comment: I'll check the keymap section once again if I changed any hotkeys, and I got the Maya plugin which makes things in blender sometimes not work as they should. I hoped there was a quick fix for this

Comment: Your pivot point is set to _3D Cursor_, this means no matter which vertex you select, the tool gizmo will always stay on the 3D cursor. Although I cannot actually see the cursor in the screenshots... but it could be disabled in the _Overlays_ or hidden somehow.